# sh script linux vacuumdb

Tags: linux, sh

I want to vacuumdb  database wsemp0331 but everytime i ran it in crontab, I'm getting this error in the log file:

```
 line 3: vacuumdb: command not found
```

The command I use is:

```
vacuumdb -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -u janet -d wsemp0331 -vz > /home/empbackup/public_html/backup/log/DBMaintenance_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.log
```

I have already added the host, port, and user.  Any idea?

The database is in the same server where the script (crontab) is located.

Comment: crontabs run with minimal settings for the PATH env var. Consult you `man crontab` to see if you can globally modify your crontab PATH, or if not, then either use `/full/path/to/vacuumdb ...` or make a wrapper script to the vacuumdb launcher that manages the PATH and other required env settings/libs/pkgs/etc. Good luck.

Comment: incidentally, searching for `crontab "command not found"` found 45 entries.

Comment: `whereis vacuumbdb` and after put on your crontab with full path. Also before put on your crontab test on shell.